# In Python, is it possible to unpack a list of strings and put a single character from each string into a generator?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7.

Let's say I have a list like so:

```
string_list = ['hello', 'apple', 'green', 'paint', 'sting']
```

Where each string in the list is the same length.

I want to create a generator that would be doing something like the following code:

```
for i in xrange(len(string_list)):
    my_gen = (ch for a_string[i] in string_list)
```

So the first run, my_gen would have 'h', 'a', 'g', 'p', s'. The next run it would have 'e', 'p', 'r', 'a', 't'.

Comment: The *zip()* function will work as long as all the inputs are the same length.  If not, see the *roundrobin()* recipe below.  It is a more general purpose solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the built-in function `zip` -

like in

```
for letters in zip('hello', 'apple', 'green', 'paint', 'sting'):
     print letters
```

zip is a built-in that does just that: combine one element of each iterable in a tuple, for each iteration.

Running the above example, you have:

```
>>> for letters in zip('hello', 'apple', 'green', 'paint', 'sting'):
...   print letters
... 
('h', 'a', 'g', 'p', 's')
('e', 'p', 'r', 'a', 't')
('l', 'p', 'e', 'i', 'i')
('l', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'n')
('o', 'e', 'n', 't', 'g')
```

Answer (score 2):

`izip` does exactly what you want:

```
from itertools import izip
for letters in izip(*string_list):
    print letters
```

The `*` operator unpacks your `string_list` so that `izip` sees it as five sequences of characters, instead of just a single list of strings.
Output:

```
('h', 'a', 'g', 'p', 's')
('e', 'p', 'r', 'a', 't')
('l', 'p', 'e', 'i', 'i')
('l', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'n')
('o', 'e', 'n', 't', 'g')
```

The built-in `zip` function works too, but it's not lazy (i.e. it immediately returns a list of all the tuples, instead of generating them one at a time).

Answer (score 1):

The following recipe comes from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import islice, cycle

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Besides being very fast, one advantage of this approach is that it works well if the input iterables are of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `zip` function that takes several lists (iterables) and yields tuples of corresponding items:

```
zip(*string_list)
```

yields (successively)

```
[('h', 'a', 'g', 'p', 's'),
 ('e', 'p', 'r', 'a', 't'),
 ('l', 'p', 'e', 'i', 'i'),
 ('l', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'n'),
 ('o', 'e', 'n', 't', 'g')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = zip('hello','apple','green','paint','sting')
```

or  `zip(*string_list)`

```
print val[0]
```

output = `('h', 'a', 'g', 'p', 's')`

```
print val[1]
```

output = `('e', 'p', 'r', 'a', 't')`

Comment: strings are already iterable, so no need to convert them to lists

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(string_list):
    for i in xrange(len(string_list)):
        yield (a_string[i] for a_string in string_list)
string_list = ['hello', 'apple', 'green', 'paint', 'sting']
for nth_string_list in foo(string_list):
    for ch in nth_string_list:
        print ch
```